# How to echo strings in PDO MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want php to echo string of text - a zone of the country from the database, but PDO does not want to spit out anything but arrays.

```
$sendToCountryCode = $_POST['sendToCountry'];

$sqlGetSendToCountryZone= "SELECT zone FROM table WHERE code = :country";
$stmtGetSendToCountryZone = $conn->prepare($sqlGetSendToCountryZone);
$stmtGetSendToCountryZone->bindParam(':country', $sendToCountryCode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmtGetSendToCountryZone->execute(array(':country' => $sendToCountryCode));

$sendToCountryZone = $stmtGetSendToCountryZone->fetch();
var_dump($sendToCountryZone);
echo 'send to country code: ', $sendToCountryZone ,'<br>';
```

Google is not strong with me today

> Notice: Array to string conversion in .... on line 10

Comment: Use `implode(",", $array);` to make a string from your array

Comment: `echo 'send to country code: ', $sendToCountryZone["zone"] ,'<br>';`

Comment: Use echo $sendToCountryZone['zone'];

Comment: Well, the actual answer would be to use `fetchColumn()`, as [per manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).

Comment: You are totally right, N.B., this works the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `$sendToCountryZone = $stmtGetSendToCountryZone->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
as it is recommended to use `fetch ()` with the appropriate parameter since `fetch ()` has several "fetching styles".

Read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Next please use $sendToCountryZone["zone"] as it will ***always*** return a string array.

Comment: $sendToCountryZone = $stmtGetSendToCountryZone->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: @e342 Oops, my bad. Use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC instead. You get this error since FETCH_ASSOC is not globally defined anywhere, obviously.

Comment: >  as fetch () requires a parameter This is not true.

Comment: @klenium improved my answer, thank you for your comment.